# Run Maven Checkstyle and fail on errors

Tags: maven, checkstyle

Beside `mvn test` and the build process I want to run Maven and it should fail on violations. I tried different options in pom.xml but nothing worked. `failOnViolation` and `failsOnError` didn't help.

I can run `mvn checkstyle:check` and it outputs the errors to the console (suing `<consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>`). But how can I run checkstyle and let it fail on violations?

This is what I tryied so far:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do it is by modifying the `violationSeverity` value.

```
<configuration>
    <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
    ...
</configuration>
```

This setup the lowest severity level that is considered a violation. Valid values are "error", "warning" and "info". More information: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the best way but I got it working. In *checkstyle.xml* the severity level is set to "warning". I switched to "error" and now the build fails on checkstyle violations.

```
<module name="Checker">
    <property name="severity" value="error"/>
...
</module>
```